# Как исключить из загрузок на Яндекс.Диск папку node modules?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, яндекс-диск

У меня есть папка в котором я собирал проекты 2019 и в нем папки с названиям проектов.
Хочу загрузить ее на яндекс диск (чтобы было на всякий случай).
Но как сделать что бы исключить папку `node modules`?

Структура:
`проекты 2019` > 30 папок в каждой `node modules`.

Comment: Надо не на яндекс диск сохранять, а на github. И использовать .gitignore.